# Release build of DirectX11 application seems to revert to Shader Model 2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, direct3d, hlsl, directx-11

I've built a GPU accelerated path tracer using VS2012/DirectX11/SM5. This works great, except that when I try to build the solution in release mode the compiler spits out an error:

```
error X3548: in vs_2_0 uints can only be used with known-positive values, use int if possible (pixelShader.hlsl)
```

This seems to indicate to me that it is somehow trying to evaluate the shader using shader model 2, but I have no idea how that could happen. The shader model option for the HLSL compiler (in the solution configuration) is set to SM5 for both the Debug and Release build.

The HLSL compiler command line options for the Release version

```
/E"main" /Fo"[projectdir]\x64\Release\%(Filename).cso" /nologo
```

The HLSL compiler command line options for the Debug version:

```
/Zi /E"main" /Od /Fo"[projectdir]\x64\Debug\%(Filename).cso" /nologo
```

I don't really know if it's relevant, but my shaders are compiled at runtime.

Compiler command line options (Release):

```
/GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"x64\Release\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Fp"x64\Release\PathTracer.pch"
```

Compiler command line options (Debug):

```
/GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\PathTracer.pch"
```

Linker command line options (Release):

```
/OUT:"[projectdir]\x64\Release\PathTracer.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"[projectdir]\x64\Release\PathTracer.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "d3d11.lib" "D3dcompiler.lib" "Winmm.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF /PGD:"[projectdir]\x64\Release\PathTracer.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\PathTracer.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Linker command line options (Debug):

```
/OUT:"[projectdir]\x64\Debug\PathTracer.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"[projectdir]\x64\Debug\PathTracer.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "d3d11.lib" "D3dcompiler.lib" "Winmm.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"[projectdir]\x64\Debug\PathTracer.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\PathTracer.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Am I even looking in the right direction? I don't really know what to look for, and Google hasn't been very helpful in providing similar cases or anything related.

Comment: *I don't really know if it's relevant, but my shaders are compiled at runtime.* - do you mean you call `D3DCompile` or some variant at run-time, or just `Create*Shader()`?  If the former, you can just set the shader items to be "excluded from build" and VS won't attempt to build them (and you don't need them built if you're only using the source at run-time).  Doesn't solve the problem but it's a workaround.

Comment: From the error message, it seems you give negative value to uint type, can you paste your shader code?

Comment: The error message doesn't mean you are using shader model 2, I guess it means start from shader model 2.

Comment: @MooseBoys thanks, excluding them worked! If you add it as an answer I can mark it as solved :)